# Permission denied when starting elasticserach cluster in rspec test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

I am using elasticsearch-ruby gem in my API application running on Ruby on Rails 6. In development env everything is running fine but for testing I wanted to create test cluster using elasticsearch-extensions gem. I am getting following error when I run rspec and trying to start server. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

```
Starting 2 Elasticsearch nodes../usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 81: /etc/default/elasticsearch: Permission denied
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 81: /etc/default/elasticsearch: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

What Elasticsearch version?
How was Elasticsearch installed?
Output from `ls -l /etc/default/elasticsearch`?

This should fix your problem if the ownership settings are wrong:

```
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /etc/default/elasticsearch
```

Per https://discuss.elastic.co/t/permission-denied-starting-elasticsearch-7-0/179336

Comment: Output of above command is as follow. I can start server normally but when I run rspec and trying to run new cluster on new port 4250 then it gives above error.

`-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 1673 Oct 16 16:13 /etc/default/elasticsearch`

Comment: Can you try exporting `DEBUG=true` to your environment and then re-running and posting the output here? It should print more information.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `TEST_CLUSTER_COMMAND` like such:

`TEST_CLUSTER_COMMAND=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`

(assuming this is the path in your case)

In my case this was happening because I configured `TEST_CLUSTER_COMMAND` to be `/usr/share/elasticsearch`, missing the `/bin/elasticsearch`